# install webpack VS install webpack-cli?

Tags: javascript, web, webpack

What is the difference installing between the two? I installed webpack globally as said on the installation page then I moved to getting started it is said there to install webpack-cli locally. CLI = Command Line Interface, Does that mean webpack do not have cli so that I have to install webpack-cli?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since webpack version 4, the command line interface got removed from the main package and added to its own repo and package.

You are obliged to install a cli aside of webpack. CLI = command line interface, webpack = main functionalities.

Comment: Right, I faced an issue where we after 1 year upgraded the webpack version from 2.6.1 to 4.29.0 and CLI commands like `node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod` stopped working and then I installed webpack-cli and it started working again.

Comment: does anyone know why two separate packages are created instead of one single package?

Comment: You upgraded 2 major versions at once and are surprised something broke, @JagjitSingh?